# How to set default view for a specific document in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want a specific file to be in Web Layout view. So I use below VBA statement on `Document_Open` subroutine.

`ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView`

But the issue here is the next files I open also open in web view.

How can I do the same without VBA? Is there any option available?

Comment: If you save it while in web view, doesn't it retain that setting for that document?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: When I set it to web view, next opening files also use the web view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workaround and simply set a view for your Normal.dotm file as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/Dtnn-IV3OnY) video.

So, you'd insert something like the following in the `AutoOpen()` Sub:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    If Documents.Count >= 1 And ProtectedViewWindows.Count = 0 Then
        ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
        ‘Set number of columns
        ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageColumns = 1
        ‘Set zoom
        ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100
        ‘Maximize window
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    EndIf
End Sub
```

The `If Documents.Count >= 1 And ProtectedViewWindows.Count = 0 Then` part just makes sure that the code won't execute if you open a file in protected mode as this would throw an error.